# problem about inequality that related to exp function

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

Let $P_m(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{t^k}{k!}$. Prove that if $x,y \in [a,b]$ then 
$$|\exp(-n(x-y)^2)-P_{2n}(-n(x-y)^2)| \le \frac{n^{2n}|b-a|^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I tried to use taylor series of  $\exp$ function but i think there is something that is reverse. Is above inequality true ? Many thanks !!

Comment: Shouldn't $P_{2n}$ in the inequality have some argument?

Comment: Tks , i edited.